# What is 'Simple Consumer Group' in Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I used the code below to find Kafka consumer groups.

```
    ListConsumerGroupsResult listConsumerGroups = admin.listConsumerGroups();
    listConsumerGroups.all().get().forEach(v -> {
        logger.info("{}", v);
    });
```

The results are as follows.

```
[main] INFO KafkaAdminClient - (groupId='test-consumer-group', isSimpleConsumerGroup=false)
[main] INFO KafkaAdminClient - (groupId='wordcount-example', isSimpleConsumerGroup=false)
```

I want to know what isSimpleConsumerGroup is.

What is simple consumer group?

Comment: `isSimpleConsumerGroup` checks If consumer group is simple or not and accordingly it returns a boolean value. The main reason to use a `SimpleConsumer` implementation is that user wants greater control over partition consumption than Consumer Groups give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an implementation of consumer-group in kafka, and the main reason of using it is **greater control over partition consumption** than other consumer group(more implementation available).

For detailed answer you can have a look at this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example